# Which one is the correct format?

Tags: word-choice, tense

For my business conversation, which of the following sentence will suit best.

> "Once I **get** the design, Let me start development work"

OR

> "Once I **got** the design, Let me start development work"

Using past tense or present tense? Which is correct?

Comment: It is the habit (and the rule) on this site that you explain us (in the question, you can edit it) which one is correct, and why. Or alternatively, which one is incorrect, and why. Or both. Otherwise, it will look like you want us to do your homework.

Comment: I am sorry @virolino, It is not like that. It is just for my own understanding. I have noted most of the people using these sentence many times in our meetings. Hence I wanted to clarify myself with the correct format.

Comment: @JG'sSpark: "It is just for my own understanding." - exactly. Please explain your understanding, even if it is not correct. You must definitely have one (understanding), if you are able to use English in meetings. Otherwise, the question risks to be closed as "asking for proof-reading".